# Refactoring templates in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have a problem of big amount of bad readable html in my angular templates. The first idea what I have is to move validation messages from templates. What approaches do you use to handle this problems?
Here is example of my template with bad smell:

```
<div class='words_new_page'>
  <h1>New word</h1>
  <form ng-submit='createWord()' name='create_word' class='create_word' novalidate>
    <div class='form-inputs'>
      <label for='word_value'>Word</label>
      <input type='text' ng-model='wordResource.word.word_value' name='word_value' id='word_value' required>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-error-word-is-required"
      ng-show="create_word.word_value.$invalid && create_word.submitted && create_word.word_value.$error.required">
      Invalid:
      <span>Word is required.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-error"
      ng-show="create_word.word_value.$invalid && create_word.submitted && create_word.word_value.$error.word_already_taken">
      Invalid:
      <span>Word is already taken.</span>
    </div>
    <div class='translations_container' ng-if='wordResource.word_translations.length'>
      <div class='translations_title'>Translation</div>
      <div class='translations'>
        <div class='translation' ng-repeat='translation in wordResource.word_translations' ng-form='innerForm'>
          <div class="custom-error custom-error-translation-name-required"
            ng-show="innerForm.translation_value.$invalid && create_word.submitted && innerForm.translation_value.$error.required">
            Translation name is required
          </div>
          <div class="custom-error custom-error-speech-part-required"
            ng-show="innerForm.speech_part.$invalid && create_word.submitted && innerForm.speech_part.$error.required">
            Speech part is required
          </div>
          <input type='text' ng-model='translation.translation_value' name='translation_value' required>
          <select ng-model='translation.speech_part_id' ng-options='speech_part.id as speech_part.name for speech_part in wordResource.speech_parts' name='speech_part' required>
          </select>
          <a ng-click='removeWordTranslation(translation)' class='remove_translation'>remove</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div><a ng-click='addWordTranslation()' class='add_word_translation'>Add translation</a></div>

    <div class='phrasal_verbs_container' ng-if='wordResource.phrasal_verbs.length'>
      <div class='phrasal_verbs_title'>Phrasal verbs</div>
      <div class='phrasal_verbs'>
        <div class='phrasal_verb' ng-repeat='phrasal_verb in wordResource.phrasal_verbs' ng-form='phrasalVerbsForm'>
          <div class="custom-error custom-error-phrasal-verbs-name-required"
            ng-show="phrasalVerbsForm.phrasal_verb_name.$invalid && create_word.submitted && phrasalVerbsForm.phrasal_verb_name.$error.required">
            Phrasal verb name is required
          </div>
          <input type='text' ng-model='phrasal_verb.name' required name='phrasal_verb_name'>
          <a ng-click='removePhrasalVerb(phrasal_verb)' class='remove_phrasal_verb'>remove</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div><a ng-click='addPhrasalVerb()' class='add_phrasal_verb_translation'>Add phrasal verb</a></div>

    <div class='form-actions'>
      <button class='grey_button login add_word' type='submit'>Create word</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Use custom directives for validations so it is more generic and re-usable. Pass messages via attributes instead of using ng-show to show and hide them and use directives to add the error div per field and use scope variables to show appropriates messages.

Comment: Can you give some links on examples of such methods?

Comment: This is a bit offtopic, but the best way to refactor is to use directives and `ng-include`.

Comment: You can check http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/directivesvalidation and http://blog.technovert.com/2014/03/angularjs-form-validation-library-directives/ for their approach or use them as is. These are the first two results on google for "angular directive form validation and messages" so feel free to look around there.